# How to create a website location with WebPack

Tags: webpack

I need to create a site (just HTML, images and JS) and for that I chose to use WebPack, which allows me to create packages with the JS and HTML that will be generated.

One of my goals is to have the site available in English and Spanish, which is accessible through a directory within the site eg: `example.com/es-es/contact.html`, while in the default language, it will be accessed through `example.com/contact.html`.

Does WebPack have any native feature that allows you to extract the original text from HTML and JS content, export to an external file (used as a repository of the text to be translated) and build this new site, without having to duplicate the files used in development?

Comment: While I'm sure webpack can do what you want, it may just be cleaner to keep separate translation files and populate the pages dynamically with JavaScript. Is there a reason you want to do this with webpack specifically?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance I believe that the HTML page already exists with the translated text, it will perform better and will facilitate indexing by search engines.